# Loop over images with variable links set by a date

Tags: javascript, html

i want to have something like an image slider, to show a "film" of satellite pictures like sat24.com.

At the end of the file link is a timestamp with a 5 minute interval.
http://de.sat24.com/image?type=infrapolair&region=de&timestamp=201608011005

I want to display them from one hour ago to 10 minutes ago.

actually it does not work and i do not know why.

```
function init() {
var timeArr = [];
var current=0;
var d = new Date();
var akt = d.getDate();
var timeArr = [];
var ONE_HOUR = 60 * 60 * 1000; /* ms */
var vor1h = new Date(d.getTime() - ONE_HOUR);   
var fivemin = 5 * 60 * 1000;
var difference = (akt - vor1h);
var diffMins = Math.round(((difference % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); // minutes
var length = diffMins / 5;
var timestamp;

for (var i=0;length-2; i++) {
      timestamp = new Date(vor1h + fivemin*i);
      timeArr.push(timestamp.getUTCFullYear().toString() + timestamp.getUTCMonth().toString() + timestamp.getUTCDate().toString() +  timestamp.getUTCHours().toString() + timestamp.getUTCMinutes().toString());
}

function satimage_loop() {
    if (current < length-2) {
        document.getElementById('sat_loop').src= "http://de.sat24.com/image?type=infrapolair&region=de&timestamp=" + timeArr[current];
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "http://de.sat24.com/image?type=infrapolair&region=de&timestamp=" + timeArr[current];
        current = current + 1;

    } else {
      current = 0;
    }
     setInterval(satimage_loop(), 1000);
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m39eh1nd/2/

Comment: `;` is missing here `var vor1h = new Date(d.getTime() - ONE_HOUR) `

Comment: correct, but that was not the problem :/

Comment: `timestamp.getUTCFullYear() + timestamp.getUTCMonth() + timestamp.getUTCDate() +  timestamp.getUTCHours() + timestamp.getUTCMinutes()` these are not strings, they are numbers, you're adding them together at the moment, you need to turn them into strings so that you can concatenate them using `+`. update to something like `timestamp.getUTCFullYear().toString() + timestamp.getUTCMonth().toString() + timestamp.getUTCDate().toString() +  timestamp.getUTCHours().toString() + timestamp.getUTCMinutes().toString()`

Comment: thanks, but still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: 
the following code is running for me

```
function init() {
var month = new Array(12);
month[0] = "01";
month[1] = "02";
month[2] = "03";
month[3] = "04";
month[4] = "05";
month[5] = "06";
month[6] = "07";
month[7] = "08";
month[8] = "09";
month[9] = "10";
month[10] = "11";
month[11] = "12";

var timeArr = [];
var current=0;
var d = new Date();

var timeArr = [];
var vor1h = new Date(d.getTime() - (1000*60*70));
var fivemin = 5 * 60 * 1000;
var length = 14;
var coeff = 1000 * 60 * 5;


for (var i=0;i<(length-2); i++) {
      var timestamp = new Date(Math.round(vor1h.getTime() / coeff) * coeff + parseInt((5 * 60 * 1000)*i));
      timeArr.push(addZero(timestamp.getUTCFullYear().toString()) + month[timestamp.getUTCMonth()] + addZero(timestamp.getUTCDate().toString()) +  addZero(timestamp.getUTCHours().toString()) + addZero(timestamp.getUTCMinutes().toString()));
}
setInterval(function satimage_loop() {
    if (current < length-2) {
        document.getElementById('sat_loop').src= "http://de.sat24.com/image?type=visual&region=de&timestamp=" + timeArr[current];
        current = current + 1;
    } else {
      current = 0;
    }
},  800);


}

function addZero(i) {
 if (i < 10) {
     i = "0" + i;
}
return i;
}
```